# Получение значений всех чекбоксов из таблицы при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Есть таблица вот такого вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: каким способом я могу при нажатии на кнопку проверить значения всех чекбоксов в таблице (checkBox.on == true || false) и те, у которых значение true добавить в массив по их тегу? (checkBox.tag = indexPath.row)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //Получаем ячейку из xib-файла
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomTableViewCell

    cell.mainLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].postName
    cell.wrapperView.isHidden = isHidden
    cell.checkBox.isHidden = isHidden
}

func confirmButtonPressed() {
   //Здесь хочу проверять, какие из чекбоксов имеют значение true
   //Здесь добавлять их в массив, например [1,2] (если нужно удалить 2 
   // и 3 запись)
   //Здесь уже удалять записи по indexPath.row
}
```

Comment: Как Вы все это добавляете? Добавьте код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С Вашим подходом необходимо пройтись по всем ячейкам в UITableView и получить состояние чекбокса. Пример:

```
func confirmButtonPressed() { {
    for i in 0..<numberOfRowsInSection { //Количество Ваших ячеек
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell //получаем ячейку
        print(cell.mainLabel.text!) //Заменить на получение состояние чекбокса и дальнейшее использование
    }
}
```

Но здесь вылезет проблема, если элементов много и ячейки будут переиспользоваться. Поэтому лучше будет вариант, если Вы добавите в posts поле для хранения состояния чекбокса или создадите отдельный массив для этого.

При выделении/снятии выделения записываете состояние в массив, а при нажатии на кнопку просто проходитесь по элементам этого массива и в зависимсоти от состояния делаете что Вам необходимо.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Буду пробовать через массив.

Answer (score 1):

```
var selects = [];
$('select[name="my_select"] option:selected').each(function(i, selected) {
    selects.push($(selected).val());
});

console.log(selects);
```